# How to identify sub query in Mariadb Explain

Tags: mariadb, explain

I'm trying to analyze the performance of a complex query in MariaDB (about 15 sub-queries).
For that I use the  `Explain` command. The result comes with a lot of derived table (`<derived2>`, `<derived>7`), the problem is how do I know which sub-query MariaDB call `<derived7>`. I know that with mysql I can use `show warnings` but this doesn't seem to work with MariaDB. Any ideas ?

### Update

here is a truncated version of the query and the execution plan.

```sql
explain extended
SELECT 
  sub.debtor_no, 
  sub.branch_code, 
  debtor_ref, 
  branch_ref, 
  min(delivery_date) AS delivery_date, 
  max(max_delivery_date) AS max_delivery_date, 
  sum(order_quantity) AS quantity, 
  sum(amount) AS amount, 
  SUM(
    GREATEST(
      0, 
      LEAST(
        order_quantity - quantity_held - quantity_to_pick, 
        available_topick - quantity_to_pick
      )
    )
  ) AS available_quantity, 
  SUM(
    IF(
      order_quantity > 0, 
      amount / order_quantity *(
        GREATEST(
          0, 
          LEAST(
            order_quantity - quantity_held - quantity_to_pick, 
            available_topick - quantity_to_pick
          )
        )
      ), 
      0
    )
  ) AS available_amount, 
  sum(quantity_held) AS quantity_held, 
  min(occasion_date) AS occasion_date, 
  group_concat(
    distinct order_comment separator ';'
  ) AS order_comment, 
  group_concat(
    distinct detail_comment separator ';'
  ) AS detail_comment, 
  sum(quantity_to_pick) AS quantity_to_pick, 
  sum(amount_to_pick) AS amount_to_pick 
FROM 
  (
    SELECT  -- select 2
      debtor_no, 
      branch_code, 
      min(so.delivery_date) AS delivery_date, 
      max(so.delivery_date) AS max_delivery_date, 
      sum(sub.order_quantity) AS order_quantity, 
      sum(
        sub.order_quantity * unit_price *(1 - discount_percent)
      ) AS amount, 
      sum(available) as available_topick, 
      sum(
        GREATEST(
          0, 
          quantity_held - COALESCE(quantity_to_pick, 0)
        )
      ) AS quantity_held, 
      min(sub.occasion_date) AS occasion_date, 
      group_concat(
        distinct so.comments separator ';'
      ) AS order_comment, 
      group_concat(
        distinct sod.comment separator ';'
      ) AS detail_comment, 
      COALESCE(
        sum(quantity_to_pick), 
        0
      ) AS quantity_to_pick, 
      sum(
        quantity_to_pick * unit_price *(1 - discount_percent)
      ) AS amount_to_pick 
    FROM 
      0_sales_order_details sod 
      JOIN 0_sales_orders so ON (
        so.order_no = sod.order_no 
        AND so.trans_type = sod.trans_type 
        AND so.trans_type = 30
      ) 
      LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT 
          sod.id, 
          so.order_no, 
          stk_code, 
          pickable.order_quantity, 
          pickable.available, 
          pickable.allocated_detail, 
          pickable.qoh, 
          to_pick.quantity AS quantity_to_pick, 
          availabily, 
          delivery_date, 
          can_wait_until_date, 
          occasion_date, 
          relegation_date, 
          expiry_date, 
          comment, 
          sod.`priority`, 
          ref, 
          sod.id AS detail_id, 
          IF(
            delivery_date > '2022-11-08', order_quantity, 
            0
          ) AS quantity_held 
        FROM 
          0_sales_order_details sod 
          JOIN 0_sales_orders so ON (
            so.order_no = sod.order_no 
            AND so.trans_type = sod.trans_type 
            AND so.trans_type = 30
          ) 
          LEFT JOIN(
            SELECT 
              detail_id, 
              SUM(quantity) quantity, 
              MAX(quantity_before) quantity_before 
            FROM 
              0_denorm_order_details_queue 
            WHERE 
              expected_location IN ('DEF') 
            GROUP BY 
              detail_id
          ) d ON (d.detail_id = sod.id) 
          LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT 
              detail_id, 
              - sum(quantity) as quantity, 
...
```

```
+------+--------------------+------------------------------+--------+-------------------------------------------------+-----------+---------+---------------------------------------------------------+-------------------+----------+-----------------------------------------------------+
| id   | select_type        | table                        | type   | possible_keys                                   | key       | key_len | ref                                                     | rows              | filtered | Extra                                               |
+------+--------------------+------------------------------+--------+-------------------------------------------------+-----------+---------+---------------------------------------------------------+-------------------+----------+-----------------------------------------------------+
|    1 | PRIMARY            | 0_cust_branch                | ALL    | PRIMARY,branch_code                             | NULL      | NULL    | NULL                                                    | 795               |   100.00 | Using temporary; Using filesort                     |
|    1 | PRIMARY            | 0_debtors_master             | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                         | PRIMARY   | 4       | fa.0_cust_branch.debtor_no                              | 1                 |   100.00 |                                                     |
|    1 | PRIMARY            | <derived2>                   | ref    | key1                                            | key1      | 8       | fa.0_cust_branch.debtor_no,fa.0_cust_branch.branch_code | 25373788271952616 |   100.00 |                                                     |
|    2 | DERIVED            | sod                          | ALL    | sorder                                          | NULL      | NULL    | NULL                                                    | 267455            |    99.90 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort        |
|    2 | DERIVED            | sod                          | eq_ref | PRIMARY,sorder                                  | PRIMARY   | 4       | fa.sod.id                                               | 1                 |    99.90 | Using where                                         |
|    2 | DERIVED            | <derived4>                   | ref    | key0                                            | key0      | 5       | fa.sod.id                                               | 10                |   100.00 |                                                     |
|    2 | DERIVED            | <derived5>                   | ALL    | NULL                                            | NULL      | NULL    | NULL                                                    | 0                 |     0.00 | Using where                                         |
|    2 | DERIVED            | so                           | ALL    | PRIMARY                                         | NULL      | NULL    | NULL                                                    | 27120             |    99.99 | Using where                                         |
|    2 | DERIVED            | sod                          | ALL    | PRIMARY                                         | NULL      | NULL    | NULL                                                    | 267455            |   100.00 | Using where                                         |
|    2 | DERIVED            | <derived16>                  | ALL    | NULL                                            | NULL      | NULL    | NULL                                                    | 0                 |     0.00 | Using where                                         |
|    2 | DERIVED            | <derived15>                  | ref    | key0                                            | key0      | 5       | fa.sod.id                                               | 2                 |   100.00 |                                                     |
|    2 | DERIVED            | <derived13>                  | ref    | key0                                            | key0      | 23      | fa.sod.stk_code                                         | 2                 |   100.00 | Using where                                         |
|    2 | DERIVED            | <derived14>                  | ref    | key0                                            | key0      | 5       | fa.sod.id                                               | 2                 |   100.00 |                                                     |
|    2 | DERIVED            | so                           | ALL    | PRIMARY                                         | NULL      | NULL    | NULL                                                    | 27120             |    99.99 | Using where; Using join buffer (flat, BNL join)     |
|   14 | LATERAL DERIVED    | 0_denorm_order_details_queue | ref    | detail_id                                       | detail_id | 5       | fa.sod.id                                               | 1                 |   100.00 | Using index                                         |
|   16 | DERIVED            | NULL                         | NULL   | NULL                                            | NULL      | NULL    | NULL                                                    | NULL              |     NULL | Impossible WHERE noticed after reading const tables |
|   13 | LATERAL DERIVED    | 0_denorm_qoh                 | ref    | stock_id                                        | stock_id  | 23      | fa.sod.stk_code                                         | 4                 |   100.00 | Using index condition                               |
|   15 | LATERAL DERIVED    | 0_denorm_order_details_queue | ref    | detail_id                                       | detail_id | 5       | fa.sod.id                                               | 1                 |   100.00 |                                                     |
|   10 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | <derived7>                   | system | NULL                                            | NULL      | NULL    | NULL                                                    | 0                 |     0.00 | Const row not found                                 |
|   10 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | <derived8>                   | ref    | key0                                            | key0      | 23      | d.stock_id                                              | 170               |   100.00 |                                                     |
|    8 | DERIVED            | 0_denorm_order_details_queue | ALL    | NULL                                            | NULL      | NULL    | NULL                                                    | 1705              |   100.00 | Using temporary; Using filesort                     |
|    7 | DERIVED            | NULL                         | NULL   | NULL                                            | NULL      | NULL    | NULL                                                    | NULL              |     NULL | Impossible WHERE noticed after reading const tables |
|    5 | DERIVED            | NULL                         | NULL   | NULL                                            | NULL      | NULL    | NULL                                                    | NULL              |     NULL | Impossible WHERE noticed after reading const tables |
|    4 | DERIVED            | 0_denorm_order_details_queue | ALL    | expected_location,detail_id,expected_location_2 | NULL      | NULL    | NULL                                                    | 1705              |    38.59 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort        |
+------+--------------------+------------------------------+--------+-------------------------------------------------+-----------+---------+---------------------------------------------------------+-------------------+----------+-----------------------------------------------------+
+-------+------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: The full query didn't fit (too many characters), so I just put the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

There are different types of "subquery"; for example: `FROM (SELECT ...)` or `JOIN (SELECT... )` is called "DERIVED".  Tip:  Derived tables tend to be inefficient; try to rewrite the query some other way.

The first 3 lines in your Explain are `FROM table` and `JOIN table`.  Everything else seems to be some form of subquery.

"Impossible WHERE noticed after reading const tables" shows up 3 times, with no clue of which is which.  They are usually easy to spot.  It is normal for `EXPLAIN` to sometimes find that it can evaluate a subquery fully; so it does so.

`EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ...`  may give more details.  (But it will be huge.)

Try posting the full query on one of the many free posting sites.

Once you have identified #7, then what will you need??

Comment: I understand there lots of subquery, but the query works fine ... most of the time. I just want to know how if there is a way to find which sub-query is called "derived"-n.

Comment: Sometimes you can tell based on the table and/or keys.

Comment: using json actually helped me to find the culprit. Beside investigating the "Impossible where" help resolves my initial problem which was this query works only most of the time.: Where there is nothing schedule to be picke, one of the table is empty which result in breaking a chain of join and the optimizer using a different plan which was extremely slow. Thanks!

Comment: @mb14 - It sounds like you needed a `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN` -- to avoid 'breaking the chain`.

Answer (score 1):

I found that , if there are no `WITH` clauses the derived number seems to correspond to the order of which the `SELECT` keyword appear in the query (regardless of the nesting). So, for example `<derived7>` would just correspond to the sub query starting with the seventh `SELECT` keyword.

In the example given `<derived3>` would be the third `SELECT`, i.e

```
  ) 
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 
      sod.id, 
      so.order_no, 
      stk_code,
```

With `WITH` clauses you would expect the derived table to not be the position of the `SELECT` defining the clauses but the position of the `FROM subquery_name` referencing the aliased query. It seems to be neither of them.

Alternatively, using `EXPLAIN EXTENDED` and then `SHOW WARNINGS` show the query "rewritten" with some select number inserting as a comment. They don't seem to match exactly but can be ...

Another way to identify the sub query is,  as @Rick James suggested,  to look at the information in the  explain result (key used, table name etc ...). I found that using `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON` gives more information which are actually usefull to identify sub queries.